# Booting Windows from Stick

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bootloader

I installed `Windows` on my `3 TiB hard disk` with an `old motherboard` where no `UEFI` is possible.

Since i wanted to install to two other Linux OS's i changed the `msdos partition table` to `gpt` via `gdisk` and `Live-CD Linux Mint` which destroyed the `windows bootloader`.

The Windows Boot Manager shows the error code and advises to repair the Bootloader with the Recovery Disk but the Disk does not work for gpt.

> How can i create a USB Stick image that boots my Windows which is on HDD?

Comment: Would you be okay if you had a option in the boot menu (I assume grub) to boot or do you have a specific reason for having a USB stick? Also what operating systems are present on the disk?

Comment: The operating systems on my disks are windows 7, Kali Linux and Linux Mint. The reason I want to boot from USB Stick is because i don't see another option to boot windows 7 while still having the two Linux OS. If it  is possible to boot windows 7 without a USB Stick that would of course be far better.

Comment: I am going to test it in a lab to be sure, but I am pretty sure it can be done without a USB stick.

Comment: it probably can be done with a disk image i think but it involved a lot of work as far as I am informed. Can you tell me how you did it after you ve finished

Comment: If you wouldn't mind booting up into Mint's live CD and giving me like a screenshot of the partion table I want to make certain I don't give you the wrong instructions. And also the order for the installation, right now I am assuming you went Windows, Mint, Kali.

Comment: Okay so, I have the first two on a grub boot loader. I am working on getting good old Windows 7 onto the list however its acting weird. I let you know tomorrow. PS. if you cant get a screen shot of your partitions a list of them in text will work just fine. Please be sure to add it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: I added the partitions in the question but someone removed it by editing the question. I have Windows 7 on /dev/sda1 with 480 GiB Linux Mint Version 18 on /dev/sda2 with 1000GiB and Kali Linux on /dev/sda3 with 1000GiB windows is ntfs filesystem the others are ext4

Comment: is there a Windows Boot Partion? Or is it just the OS partition?

Comment: Is there a "BIOS boot partition" on GPT disk - special partition to enable BIOS boot?

Comment: There is just the OS Partition